# Get access to the v-slot value inside of the script tag

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, v-slot

I am trying to show a loading indicator which is located inside of a component that contains a slot element (lets call this the wrapper component). To do this, I have a function inside the wrapper that sets the state of the indicator based on an input boolean (`setSpinnerVisible()`). Now, I would like to execute this function from the component that uses this wrapper. To do this, in the parent component I use the v-slot property to get a reference to the function. I would like to be able to call this function inside the `mounted()` function, or from a function within `methods`.

However, I am not able to figure out how to do this. The only way I can think of is by passing this v-slot value into a function that is executed on an event like a button press, which works, but I also want to be able to call this method from a function that is not executed by an action in the layout (e.g. in the `mounted()` function).

This is (a part of) my wrapper component (the function that toggles the spinner is left out for brevity):

```html
<template>
    <slot v-bind:setSpinnerVisible="setSpinnerVisible"></slot>
    ...
    <div class="spinner" v-show="spinnerVisible"></div>
</template>
```

This is (a part of) the component that uses the wrapper:

```html
<Wrapper v-slot="{ setSpinnerVisible }">
    ...
</Wrapper>
```

I would like to be able to use the value of `setSpinnerVisible` inside the `mounted` function in one way or another, something like this fictional piece of code:

```html
<script>
export default {
    mounted() {
        this.setSpinnerVisible(true)
    }
}
</script>
```

I am using Vue 2.6.11

Comment: Have you considered $refs? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements

Comment: @Reinier68 No I did not, but it seems like a good option for my use case. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches you could take.

1. For example, you could access the parent instance and call the method you need:

   this.$parent.setSpinnerVisible()
2. Alternatively, you could create a gateway component that uses the Wrapper, gets setSpinnerVisible and passes it as a prop to the component that needs it.
3. You can use dependency injection. Described here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Dependency-Injection

So, in Wrapper.vue

```html
<template>
    ...
</template>
<script>
export default {
    provide () {
        return {
            setSpinnerVisible: this.setSpinnerVisible
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

And in your child component:

```html
<Wrapper>
    ...
</Wrapper>
<script>
export default {
    inject: ['setSpinnerVisible'],
    mounted() {
        this.setSpinnerVisible(true)
    }
}
</script>
```

The last one would be my recommended approach because it's much neater and is not anti-pattern.

Comment: Your code seems like a good and robust approach, but for my usecase it requires me to put the contents of the wrapper in its own component, which creates an (for now) seemingly unnecessary abstraction.